# spark- find the len of each row (python)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I wrote this code:

```
logFile = sc.textFile("\README.md") #read the file

def lengthfunction(line):
    return len(line) 

logFile.map(lambda line: line.split()).reduce(lengthfunction)
```

It gave me an error:

```
"lengthfunction() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"
```

I also tried

```
logFile.map(lambda line: line.split()).reduce(lambda line: len)
```

But that did not work too.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
logFile.map(lambda line: line.split()).map(len)
```

Comment: You need to explain what actually happening with your answer

Comment: thank you it's working

can you explain why my code was wrong?

and what is the different?

Comment: map: apply your function to each RDD. reduce: aggregate every RDD. In map function, you have only one input after lambda, but in reduce function there are two inputs.